# Create a clojure map threading macro ( map-> )

Tags: clojure

I'm inspired by [clojure's 1.5 `cond->` macro.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#24-new-threading-macros)

Similarily, I want to create a macro of the same idea, applied to the function `map`. However, I have no idea where to start.

For example, I can't find the source for `cond->`. (probably because it's not released yet)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain "the same idea, applied to the function `map`"?

Comment: @mobyte "the same idea" as in using `map` as the function among a series of statements for the purpose making code readable.

Comment: Could you give an example of usage?

Answer (score 3):

There is the source of `cond->` https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6742

Comment: Thanks for that reference! It seems obvious now to look for it there first.

Answer (score 2):

there are a variety of [threading macros](http://palletops.com/thread-expr/autodoc/pallet.thread-expr-api.html) from the pallet project folks including apply-map-> which looks close to, though not exactly what you are looking for.

```
(letfn [(apply-map-
          [arg f arg-coll]
          `(let [arg# ~arg]
             (apply ~f arg#
                    ~@(butlast arg-coll)
                    (apply concat ~(last arg-coll)))))]

  (defmacro apply-map->
    "Apply in a threaded expression.
   e.g.
      (-> :a
        (apply-map-> hash-map 1 {:b 2}))
   => {:a 1 :b 2}"
    [arg f & arg-coll]
    (apply-map- arg f arg-coll))
```

Perhaps there will be enough examples there for you to pick out what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand -- you want to write a macro that takes a list of partial function calls, and for each one, adds `map` (or `apply map`) to the beginning, and the previous result to the end?

While this doesn't directly answer how to write that macro, I wanted to point out that you have a couple of alternatives.

## Factor out `map`

This is always true for pure functions:

```clj
(=
  (map g (map f coll))
  (map (comp g f) coll))
```

The refactored version only walks the collection once, and no intermediate collections need to be made.

Here's what it looks like with threading:

```clj
(=
  (->> coll
       (map f)
       (map g))

  (map #(->> % f g) coll))
```

[Here's a concrete example in JS.](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch06.html#a-principled-refactor)

## Transducers

[Transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) are another pattern for doing this kind of thing in Clojure that work on more than just `map`. They're sort of an abstraction over reducer functions. Clojure's `map` / `filter` / `reduce` (etc.) will create a transducer if called without a collection. You can chain them with `comp` and use them in various contexts (lazy, eager, observable, whatever). [Rich Hickey's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII) on them is a good intro.